# Show that $G$ contains infinitely many elements of order 2.

Tags: group-theory, functions, discrete-mathematics

could a get some help or hints on how to solve this one?

Let $t_{a,b} : R → R$ denote the function defined by: $t_{a,b}(x) = ax + b$,

where $a, b ∈ R$. Show that $G = (t_{a,b} | a, b ∈ R, a ≠ 0)$ forms
a group under the operation of composition. Show that $G$ contains infinitely many elements of order 2.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: This is essentially just applying definitions.

Comment: What is $R$? If it is some finite ring then the claim is false. If it stands for the field of real numbers, then think reflections about the point $x_0$.

Answer (score 4):

Note that $t_{a,b}^2(x)=a^2x+b(a+1)$. Hence $t_{a,b}$ has order $2$ if and only if $a^2=1$ and $b(a+1)=0$. Can you find infinitely many such pairs $(a,b)$?

Comment: Actually, $t_{a,b}$ has order $1$ for $(a,b)=(1,0)$, and not $2$, of course.